# iAd Multiple Views without NavigationController

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, iad

Today I finished my project and wanted to upload it to the AppStore. Now I want to implement iAd. 
I have 4 views in my application and switch via

```
  [self presentModalViewController:eas animated:YES];
```

between them. I want to show an iAd banner in all of them. I found shared iAd on the internet but it just works with navigationcontrollers or tab bars. Is there another option of me to implement iAd in every view?

Cheers
V. Lietz.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of UIViewController which sets up the iAd and use it for your viewcontrollers.

The better way to do this (to avoid subclassing which locks you into using that subclass) would probably be to create a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) for UIViewController that sets up the iAd and just use that.